# jsdatatable TableTools buttons not working when used in dropdown menu collection

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I am using `TableTools` for `JS Datatable`

```
    tableTools:
        sSwfPath: "/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        sRowSelect: 'multi'
        sSelectedClass: 'row_selected'
        bHeader: true
        aButtons: [
            {
                sExtends: 'collection',
                sButtonText: 'Tools <span class="caret" />',
                aButtons: [
                    {
                        sExtends: 'copy'
                        mColumns: 'visible'
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                    },
                    {
                        sExtends: 'xls',
                        sFileName: '*.xls',
                        mColumns: 'visible',
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                    },
                    {
                        sExtends: 'pdf'
                        mColumns: 'visible'
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                    },
                    {
                        sExtends: 'csv'
                        mColumns: 'visible'
                        bSelectedOnly: true
                    },
                    'select_all',
                    'select_none'
                ]
            }
            'print',
        ]
```

It produces following dropdown menu:
[image]

The menu items are not working expect selec/deselect.
When I don't use `collection` and just display buttons in one row everything works perfectly fine.

How should one properly deine buttons when extending collection?

The produced HTML for dropdown looks like this:

```
<ul class="DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 551.3125px; top: 553px; opacity: 1;">
   <li class=" DTTT_button_copy" id="ToolTables_agencies_1" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies">
      <a>Copy</a>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 160px; height: 26px; z-index: 99;">
         <embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" src="/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="160" height="26" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=1&amp;width=0&amp;height=0" wmode="transparent">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class=" DTTT_button_xls" id="ToolTables_agencies_2" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies">
      <a>Excel</a>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 160px; height: 26px; z-index: 99;">
         <embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_2" src="/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="160" height="26" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_2" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=2&amp;width=0&amp;height=0" wmode="transparent">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class=" DTTT_button_pdf" id="ToolTables_agencies_3" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies">
      <a>PDF</a>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 160px; height: 26px; z-index: 99;">
         <embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_3" src="/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="160" height="26" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_3" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=3&amp;width=0&amp;height=0" wmode="transparent">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="DTTT_button_csv" id="ToolTables_agencies_4" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies">
      <a>CSV</a>
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 160px; height: 26px; z-index: 99;">
         <embed id="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_4" src="/static/external/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" loop="false" menu="false" quality="best" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="160" height="26" name="ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_4" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars="id=4&amp;width=0&amp;height=0" wmode="transparent">
      </div>
   </li>
   <li class="DTTT_button_text" id="ToolTables_agencies_5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies"><a>Select all</a></li>
   <li class="DTTT_button_text disabled" id="ToolTables_agencies_6" tabindex="0" aria-controls="agencies"><a>Deselect all</a></li>
</ul>
```

additionally it creates div with background:

```
<div class="DTTT_collection_background" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 936px; width: 1054px; opacity: 0.25;"></div>
```

in CSS I set `z-index`:

```
ul.DTTT_dropdown.dropdown-menu
    z-index: 9998
    &li
        z-index: 9999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was wit wrong positioning of DIV's containing this small piece of flash which makes the magic.

When you place DIV with position property set to `absolute` inside LI you have to quarantee, that LI's position is set to `relative`

I make it works by this piece of CSS:

```
.DTTT_button_copy, .DTTT_button_xls, .DTTT_button_pdf,.DTTT_button_csv {
    position: relative
}
```

Comment: Hi @andi, I did the same but not luck. Can you please help for suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is based on the fact the buttons have sequential naming of 'id' attribute.

ex

```
ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_1
ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_2
ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_3
```

So based on where your 'copy' button appears in the sequence. You may add the following css style.

```
#ZeroClipboard_TableToolsMovie_3 { height: 29px;  width: 43px; }
```

This will convert the non-flash 'copy' button to flash based button right after the data-table comes out of hiding. Thereby making it work without needing to click on the 'Export' (Collection button)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding another class :

> flash-relative

with relative position :

```
<style>
        .flash-relative{
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
```

then create the datatable with buttons :

```
buttons: {
  buttons: [
            {extend: 'excel',className: 'dropdown-item flash-relative'},
            {extend: 'pdf',className: 'dropdown-item flash-relative'}
           ]
         }
```

> dropdown-item  : just for dropdown bootstrap style

and try using this `buttons.resize()` when dropdown is shown :

`$("#dropdown_ID").on("shown.bs.dropdown", function (event) {
        $.fn.dataTable.tables({api: true}).buttons.resize();
    });`

@NullPointer : try to stop dropdown from closing:

`$('#dropdown_ID a.flash-relative').on("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });`

> I have `<a>` not `<li>` element